# Filtrar datas utilizando WP_query e Post meta no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

estou desenvolvendo uma categoria de eventos em meu template utilizando o post padrão, neste post adicionei dois campos (Metabox) para data inicial e data final do evento. Já no WP_query eu preciso exibir os eventos que possuam a data inicial menor que a data atual, e a data de finalização menor.

Utilizando WP_query ou get_post_meta, ou qualquer outra função... Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Esta salvando a data como? Em que formato?

Comment: Formato da data: d/m/Y

Comment: Sinceramente esta é a pior forma de salvar, se salvar como Ymd fica tranquilo para fazer as consultas.

Comment: Sim, mas meu problema é como fazer a consulta, pois não sei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso isso depende da forma que você salva a data... Eu recomendo usar o formato:

```
YmdHis
```

Desta forma pode fazer uma consulta bem simples comprando números apenas:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'seu_meta_key',
        'value' => array( 'data_atual', 'data_termino' ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )
);
```

Também pode tentar usar o `type` como `DATE`, mas para fazer isso também vai ter que usar um formato de data como falei.

Para mais detalhes consulte documentação do uso do [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) em `WP_Query`.